# Adding a helper class to an Orchard CMS theme

Tags: orchardcms

I created a new folder in my theme called helper and added a helper class but could not reference the namespace from the view. I also can't reference the namespace if I add the helper class to Orchard.Themes.

Comment: Have you precompiled the solution locally first after adding your class? Just putting a class in a folder will not make it work.